# Html text input accepting single space in required field in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

We have AngularJS application. 
Suppose we have one text input, and we make it as required field.

```
<input id="TitleTextField" name="TitleTextField" 
ng-model="myDto.Title" type="text" 
required 
maxlength="255" />
```

We have check validation for same in controller like

```
 angular.forEach(error.required, function (field) {
 });
```

But it is accepting single blank space.
How to restrict this behaviour, means I want that input field should acccept text with spaces, like 'xyz pqr'
But not a single space ?

Comment: How are you validating? It's impossible to help without this information.

Comment: Can you post your validation code here? As @daveyfaherty has noted, we couldn't do much without this information.

Comment: Essentially you need to use trim() but who knows how to help with that without more information. It's something ng-validate does automatically.

Comment: I had the same exact issue. It turned out that once of the scripts was trying to clear the input after submitting data to DB. The line of code: ( $scope.newRule = " ";)  There was a space between the two quotation marks which was filling the field.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-trim="false"` and you will get the desired result

Comment: That's the opposite of what he wants.

Comment: Maybe, but I understood it this way. lets him clarify.

Comment: I want a text input which can accept text with space but not just a space without text.

Comment: Then you need `ng-trim="true"` but that is default, so it should work for you.